# Getting Exception in triggering quartz job

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I'm using `quartz-1.8.4` with `spring 3.2.18.RELEASE` but facing issues with `quartz scheduling`. I can't use `quartz 2.x` as `DB2` doesn't support it. I recently upgraded `spring` from `2.5.1` to `3.2.18.RELEASE`. Our application uses `DB2` as a database and everything is working fine except `quartz scheduling`.

Below are the `quartz` related dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
<!-- Quartz dependency library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
            <version>9.7.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>9.7.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
            <version>9.7.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Exception as follows:

```
     [org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger] (scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread) An error occured while scanning for the next trigger to fire.: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'springNonTxDataSource.scheduler': java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/jdbc/abc_datasource [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/jdbc/abc_datasource]
     at   
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreCMT.java:165) [quartz-1.8.4.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3760) [quartz-1.8.4.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2728) [quartz-1.8.4.jar:]
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:264) [quartz-1.8.4.jar:]
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/jdbc/abc_datasource
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore$2.getConnection(LocalDataSourceJobStore.java:131) [spring-context-support-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
        at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:109) [quartz-1.8.4.jar:]
        at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreCMT.java:162) [quartz-1.8.4.jar:]
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/jdbc/abc_datasource
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:421)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:510)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:143)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000658: Unexpected throwable while trying to create a connection: null
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:421)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:453)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:425)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:354)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:356)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:304)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:834)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:379)
        ... 12 more
    Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][3.62.56] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection underlying socket, socket input stream, 
    or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1).  Message: Software caused connection abort: recv failed. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:319) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:461) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:456) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.b(z.java:209) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.c(z.java:268) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.c(z.java:381) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.v(z.java:1149) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:45) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.n(b.java:1251) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1123) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:717) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:703) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:389) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:318) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:214) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:460) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:328)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) [rt.jar:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) [rt.jar:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) [rt.jar:1.8.0_171]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.b(z.java:199) [db2jcc-9.7.4.jar:]
        ... 28 more
```

Comment: From the error it seems quartz is not able to connect to the datasource you have configured using jndi.Could you confirm that this data-source is configured properly java:/jdbc/adm_UDB_datasource.

Comment: Data Source is configured properly and I'm able to perform other CRUD operations from application using this datasource.

Comment: Looking further down at the stack trace it suggests that there is exception in connection.Please have a look at this https://www.international-presence.com/wikidocs/index.php?title=Connecting_to_DB2

Comment: I doubt whether it's related to spring version upgrade as earlier app was using spring 2.5.1 and was working fine but when I upgraded it to spring 3.2.18.RELEASE, I'm facing this error.

Comment: Does it fails at application start-up or after sometime.If it fails after sometime or when few jobs have been triggered i doubt there might be a connection leak as it is not able to get connection from the jndi resource.

Comment: It fails after sometime when the application starts. But this issue is only in quartz scheduling. Rest of the CRUD operations are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. Actually there was connection issue on that day. I was running it locally and the connection was being used by another environment. That's why my local app was unable to acquire connection.